# How can I get a list of domain names managed by a DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

For example, how can I get a list of domains whose name server is ns1.example.com? If it is not possible to get the complete list, can I get part of the list?

Comment: Various online services give you that, but not for free. How they do it? "Easy". You resolve "all" names, you record the nameservers used, you store the data, and now you can answer queries such as yours. With various limits, like getting really all domains, or the freshness of data. It also depends why you need this data. Registrars can have part of this data from reports done by  registries. But few will expose that to end clients most probably.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short: unless you have the access to the DNS server configuration files on the *ns1.example.com* - you can't. There's no technical way to ask the NS "hey, mate, what zones do you serve ?". You can only ask if it serves a certain specific zone.